# What is best way to show the select box data which is long(almost one line sentence)

Tags: usability, gui-design, layout, ux-field, human-interface-guideline

I have list box to show the select box data which is long(almost one line sentence). I cant make list box which look very big.

For all sentence I have can use some code(Say for 'Sentence1' I can use short-form as "A")

What is best way to show list box in such condition.

**List box**

```
<select>
<option>Long Sentence1....</option>
<option>Long Sentence2....</option>
</select>
```

Not necessary list box. I just want precise option.

Thanks

Comment: Let us know more: Why can't you make big list boxes - Is there much more content to be shown? Or does it have to fit onto a mobile screen? And what do you mean by "I can use some code" - Do your users know the codes already? If not, how do you think they can link the code with the sentence?

Comment: yes content is bigger say almost 2 lines. Not for mobile screen for now. User don't know about code, I was thinking I can have some code kind which will look simple (on click of code some popup will showup --just thought )

Comment: I get that the content of the select box is big (up to two lines). What about the rest of the UI? I am not getting the reason why you are worried about the size of the selection.

Comment: I list box will have 13 options an each is of 2 lines. Hence that much big list box will not go with the design and also it won't look good each list with 2 lines.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use dropdown ? Why can't you go with a checkbox list ?

Comment: Not necessary list box. I just want precise option.

Comment: If you don't have to use a drop down select - I would use a list of checkboxes or radio buttons, dependent on the functionality required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pop-up with full sentence when the user hovers on the short sentence line would be a solution.

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution for my current issue. Do you know of any implementations from which I could learn how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be if you definitely need to display the data in a drop-down select list to keep the width of the field fixed and expand it on selection. The options could wrap inside the list as well. 
Though when a value is selected it will not fit all for display

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Upon First Glance

I believe your answer lies in the marquee effects, previously answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337330/javascript-marquee-to-replace-marquee-tags.

My favorite has to be this one:
http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

---

### A Preferred Design Choice

I love Apple's solution (personal bias), which is to display the text normally for a moment before scrolling if needed until it came back to default and pausing before the next cycle. Sadly I believe a custom JQuery or JavaScript approach is in order if you wish to achieve the best results.

---

### A Responsive Touch

For a good marquee effect based in the first link (silky smooth marquee) the function would have to add instead of:

```
$('marquee').marquee(optionalClass);
```

Would need to:

**1** Give horizontal overflow to `.marquee` classes in CSS *(keeping them single lined)*:

```
.marquee {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

**2** Load the gistfile1.js (I'd name it "marquee.js") found [here](https://gist.github.com/2484402)

**3** Check all `$('.marquee')` for overflowed content *(in this case your buttons)*

**4** Apply marquee as necessary

**5** Recheck whenever the page resizes

```
function isOverflowed(element){
  return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight || element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth;
}
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $('.marquee').each(function(){
    if(isOverflowed($(this))) $(this).marquee();
  });
});
```

*isOverflowed function credit: [micnic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/883970/micnic) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333379/javascript-css-check-if-overflow*

Hope this helps you!